# how to avoid of duplicate clauses in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need filter my tasks table by several conditions.

```
select * from tasks where initialPrice > 20 where status = 3
```

But if this tasks belongs to userId = 1 (for example) - I need to select it with other additional statuses (with status = 1 and status = 5).
So my variant is:

`select * from tasks where initialPrice > 20 and status = 3 or (status = 1 or status = 5 and userId = 5 and initialPrice > 20)`

Is it possible to avoid duplication of conditions and what is the best way to build this query?

P.S. In further this query will use with the multiple joins and it will be hard to duplicate joins and conditions in both part of this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from tasks 
where initialPrice > 20 
and case when status = 3 Then 1 when status in (1,5) and userId = 5 Then 1 else 0 end = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `case` expressions in the `where` clause is generally discouraged.  One reason is because it makes the query harder to optimize.  A second reason is that limiting such conditions to boolean logic is easier for people to understand.

So, I would suggest:

```
select t.*
from tasks t
where initialPrice > 20 and status = 3 and
      (userId <> 1 or status in (1, 5);
```

or:

```
select t.*
from tasks t
where initialPrice > 20 and
      (user = 1 and status in (1, 3, 5) or
       user <> 1 and status = 3 
      )
```